# Definition of derivative to calculate $x\sqrt{|x|}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So the question says use the definition of the derivative to calculate the derivative of $x\sqrt{|x|}$ at $x=0$. I understand the definition of derivative but have no idea where to go from there to even attempt.  Help?

Comment: You've got an answer, but in a deeper sense, it's important to examine why you "understand the definition" but are unable to apply it. The strategy is identical for an arbitrary function: Write down a difference quotient and take a limit. (If the function is built by adding/multiplying/composing functions of known derivative, you can instead apply formal calculational rules, hence the name _differential calculus_.)

Comment: How can you say that you understand the definition if you are not able to simply apply it?

Comment: "I understand the definition of derivative" So what happened when you wrote down $(f(x) - f(0))/(x-0)$ and then plugged in?

Comment: I realized what I did before I had gotten an answer here.  When I posted the question i had been up for about 30 hours and for some reason in my infinite tired wisdom my brain never connected "at x=0" to plugging in 0 for x.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\sqrt{|h|}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\sqrt{|h|}=0.$$

Comment: A warning to the OP: Most rigorous derivative problems aren't this easy.

Comment: Just a side note: $f(h)$ is simply replacing the $x$ in the function with $h$. That's how @Surb got $h\sqrt{|h|}$ for $f(h)$ since that is required in the definition of a derivative.

Comment: Yeah I commented above but I will comment here too. I had just gotten off my second 16 hour shift in 2 days when I posted this.  When i woke up this was really easy but my exhausted brain never connected "at x=0" to plugging in 0 for x.  It was stupid of me to post here when all I needed was some sleep.